# string.Format equivalent that doesn't throw exception with extra marker

Tags: c#, .net, string, .net-4.0, string-formatting

I want end user of my application to edit format string that is used in `string.Format`. I want to do that to give user ability to edit templates. Problem occurs when user enters too much markers.

This works fine:

```
var result = string.Format("test {0}, {1}, {2}", 1, 2, 3);
```

this works too:

```
var result = string.Format("test {0}, {1}", 1, 2, 3);
```

but this throws exception:

```
var result = string.Format("test {0}, {1}, {2}", 1, 2);
```

> System.FormatException: 'Index (zero based) must be greater than or
>   equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.'

I'm aware that I must add as much parameters as there are markers, but end user don't know that, or he can make mistakes - add extra marker.

My question is:
Can I use similar approach to format string in a way `string.Format` works but without exception.

I know I could use `try\catch` block and return format string, but I don't want to do that.

I've build very simple method that replace markers in string:

```
public static string SafeFormat(string format, params object[] args)
{
    var result = format;
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        result = result.Replace($"{{{i}}}", args[i].ToString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

but this isn't supporting formatting of data that is used in place of markers.

Internally `string.Format` is using `AppendFormatHelper` (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,2c3b4c2e7c43f5a4) that is more complex than my simple replace.

Ideally `string.Format("test {0}, {1}, {2}", 1, 2)` should return `test 1, 2, {2}`

Comment: If the user has provided an inappropriate format string for the number of items you're going to provide, I think you *should* flag that up as an error. Better to report an error to the user early than to create basically useless data. Presumably the user expects a certain value to be in the output - just including `{2}` isn't going to help them.

Comment: @JonSkeet I can't agree more, unfortunately I'm not building app from scratch, system is more complex and adding functionality that checks template for errors to existing module would require a lot work, especially it's very old system. I recently started building new version of template management module that is using different approach, but it won't be ready soon enough, so for now I need a temporary solution. Those templates are used only for email notifications, so if there is extra marker user will notice that in email.

Comment: Well in that case, why not just pass extra values in? `string.Format(formatString, realValue0, realValue1, "undefined", "undefined", "undefined")`?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to check how many values are expected, and just append others to argument list (null or placeholders). Example string extension:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string SafeFormat(this string value, params object[] args)
    {
        var pattern = @"{(.*?)}";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(value, pattern);
        var matchCount = matches.Count;
        if (matchCount > args.Length)
        {
            var argsExtended = args.ToList();
            for (int i = args.Length; i < matchCount; i++)
            {
                argsExtended.Add($"{{{i}}}"); //Can add null value to erase them
            }
            return string.Format(value, argsExtended.ToArray());
        }
        return string.Format(value, args);
    }
}
```

You can easily change this to method if you want